# Sum array of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, filtering

I have the below array

```
[
   {item_id:1,quantity:5},
   {item_id:1,quantity:10},
   {item_id:2,quantity:45},
   {item_id:2,quantity:30},
   {item_id:2,quantity:20}
   {item_id:3,quantity:10},
]
```

Now i want to get the sum of each item_id
so the result will be the below array

```
[
   {item_id:1,quantity:15},
   {item_id:2,quantity:95},
   {item_id:3,quantity:10},
]
```

Could you please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into how the `.map()` or `.reduce()` function works for Arrays in JavaScript?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FPLBGFR3QDXI